# I am doing the CS50 web development with python and JS. I am at lecture 3 and having this problem in my list.py:

Tags: python

```
import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine("postgresql://postgres:Goodtime80@localhost:5432/flights")
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))


def main():
    flights = db.execute("SELECT origin, destination, duration FROM flights").fetchall()
    for flight in flights:
        print(f"{flight.origin} to {flight.destination}, {flight.duration} minutes.")


if name == "main":
    main()
```

I get this error when running it

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  database "flights" does not exist

(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PostgreSQL server doesn't have a database called `flights`.

Are you sure that's the name of the *database* (the name of the *table* could well be `flights`)?

Have you created the database (and probably imported some data into it)?